# MS Word datepicker content control Arabic Transliteration of month names

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word, you can choose the date then use the format you need to show the date.

In Arabic, only Arabic names of months can be displayed like:

January => كانون الثاني

February => شباط

I need to choose the month in Arabic transliteration form.

January => يناير

February => فبراير

I tried to change the locale into other Arabic countries but in vain.

The following picture depicts what I mean.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to use *English* transliterated names for gregorian months when writing in Arabic, and that instead of Arabic names for Gregorian months which are commonly used in east Mediterranean countries minus Egypt

**To use English transliterated names for Gregorian months**

1. Go to **File \ Options**. The *Word Options* dialogue box opens.
2. On the left to the dialogue box, select **Advanced** tab
3. Grouped under *Show document content*, look for *Month names* and change
   from **Arabic** to **English transliterated** from the drop down menu.
4. Click **OK** and re-insert the date. Or if you use fields, right click the field and pick **Update Field** from the context menu

If this answer fixes your problem, mark it so you help other people seeking help on this problem

Comment: Great . It worked like a charm. Thank you very much 